# General linear test

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, linear

I have a two-part question:

- There is a section devoted to the *general linear test* in Applied Linear Statistical Models by Kutner et al. It is presented as an equivalent test for both linear regression and ANOVA, where you can compare a full and reduced model with an F-test (as opposed to obtaining the F-test through the ANOVA-table ($MSTR/MSE$).
  However, this name does not seem to be used by everyone (it is not mentioned on wikipedia, CrossValidated, etc.). Is there another name for this test? At first I thought it might refer to partial f-tests, but this name is reserved for another situation, in this textbook at least.
- Is there any relation between this *general linear test* and likelihood-ratio tests? I'm not that familiar with the former, but I do know that they are used to compare nested models. Aren't we also comparing nested models when doing a general linear test of the full and reduced model of a linear regression with one (or more) parameters removed?